# Regex for polynomial expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regular-language, polynomials

could someone help me create a Java regex for the following polynomial expression?

Expression: 9x^2 + 4x + 2

---

Ive so far not been able to map the constant and im not sure if this is the best way but this is whats from my best understanding:

(-?\b\d+) [xx] || ^ (-?\d+\b)

---

Any help is much appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general regex pattern, which should work for a polynomial of any order:

```
^\d{0,}(?:[a-z](?:\^\d+)?)?(?: [+-] \d{0,}(?:[a-z](?:\^\d+)?)?)*$
```

### Demo

I will explain the first portion of the regex, which matches any single polynomial term.  The second repeating portion of the regex just recycles this pattern, with a +/- separator in between.

```
\d{0,}          match zero or more numbers (coefficients)
(?:             turn off capturing
    [a-z]       match a single variable letter
    (?:\^\d+)?  then match an optional exponent term
)?              close group
```

Note that we handle the optional exponent by grouping it with the variable.  Then, we make that entire group optional.